# Confusing problem with an info.plist key related to HealthKit - Apple

Tags: ios, healthkit, info.plist

today I managed to run into a very weird error related to Info.plist key's in an app that uses WatchKit / WatchKit Extensions. The key in question here is `NSHealthUpdateUsageDescription`. This is needed along with a short description when any data is tracked related to the [HealthKit](https://developer.apple.com/healthkit/) provided by Apple.

The tricky detail here is, when "Archiving" a build of said app in preparation for submission. XCode says "Missing key `NSHealthUpdateUsageDescription` is needed for the reason mentioned above.

When the build of the app lands on the AppStore Connect page, its pointing too because of its bundle id, it process then will disappear and will have an error message from apple saying this.

> Dear Developer,
>
> We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app,
>   "AirTime - Count your jumps!". Please correct the following issues,
>   then upload again.
>
> Missing Purpose String in Info.plist File - Your app's code references
>   one or more APIs that access sensitive user data. The app's Info.plist
>   file should contain a NSHealthUpdateUsageDescription key with a
>   user-facing purpose string explaining clearly and completely why your
>   app needs the data. Starting Spring 2019, all apps submitted to the
>   App Store that access user data will be required to include a purpose
>   string.If you're using external libraries or SDKs, they may reference
>   APIs that require a purpose string. While your app might not use these
>   APIs, a purpose string is still required. You can contact the
>   developer of the library or SDK and request they release a version of
>   their code that doesn't contain the APIs. Learn more
>   (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/protecting_the_user_s_privacy).
>
> Best regards,
>
> The App Store Team

Searching SO, I haven't found any post's related to info.plist key problems outside of things dealing with CFBundleIcons etc. This isn't a duplicate I feel as if this is a question that would be useful to future developers when answered.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your code references to API that access to sensitive data from user (in your case you need access to updating Health data). When you want to access this data, you have to ask user for permission. This you can do in Info.plist by adding this key to Info.plist.

You can also add string describing why you need what you're asking access for. In reply from The App Store Team is written that this string with clear purpose will be required since Spring 2019 so you should try to use it even now.

In this case you should set string with clear purpose for key `NSHealthUpdateUsageDescription`, why you need to update Health data.

[image]

Comment: Have you seen this before `WatchKit v3 app has disallowed Info.plist key: NSHealthShareUsageDescription`

I know NSHealthUpdateUsageDescription and  NSHealthShareUsageDescription are needed if you read and write data..

Answer (score 0):

The problem here was.. the `NSHealthUpdateUsageDescription and NSHealthShareUsageDescription` aren't needed in the WatchKit Info.plist like I assumed from Apples Error Message..

Future note for anyone that finds this question `NSHealthUpdateUsageDescription` is needed in your Info.plist if you are "reading" data you are tracking.. this could mean multiple things but for this example say you are tracking data and posting it to a leaderboard.. you need this key!

`NSHealthShareUsageDescription` is used when you are "writing" to data you are tracking..

Hopefully this question is helpful to someone running into the same problem in the future!

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

In case of my standalone WatchOS app with access to Health Kit this helped:

1. I added the keys "Privacy - Health Share Usage Description" and "Privacy - Health Update Usage Description" with some text as values in the file Info.plist in the folder [MyApp] WatchKit Extension.
2. Then I created another folder [MyApp] on the same level as the folder [MyApp] WatchKit Extension. I copied the Info.plist file from the folder [MyApp] WatchKit Extension to the new folder [MyApp] and deleted all keys except the two mentioned above.
3. Then under Targets (you get there when you click on your project name in the Project Navigator on the top of the left side in Xcode), I clicked on the first target (MyApp) and under Packaging for the key "Info.plist File" I added the path to the new Info.plist file - [Myapp]/Info.plist

I cleaned the build folder and got an error when I tried to build again (under top menu Product - Build) - some new error:
(error: Multiple commands produce '[...]/Info.plist': [...]

I restarted XCode, cleaned the build folder again and clicked on Build again. This time I was asked if it was ok if something was cleaned and I accepted.

Then it worked.

Note: In the past, I also had the keys mentioned above in the Info.plist file in [MyApp] WatchKit App and as I remember it caused problems. So in that file I do not have these two keys.

My answer is based on this one: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/122660?answerId=382719022#382719022
I later found also this [post](https://learningswift.brightdigit.com/independent-watch-app-healthkit-permissions/).